# Ble Mouse on ios

Tags: c

I am using the library to apply to my project
But I'm not sure what this means.
Is the unit of 127 pixels?

```
LOGICAL_ MINIMUM(1), 0x81, // LOGICAL_ MINIMUM (-127)   
LOGICAL_ MAXIMUM(1), 0x7f, // LOGICAL_ MAXIMUM (127)   
REPORT_ SIZE(1), 0x08, // REPORT_ SIZE (8) 
REPORT_ COUNT(1), 0x01, // REPORT_ COUNT (1)
```

[ESP32-BLE-Mouse](https://github.com/T-vK/ESP32-BLE-Mouse/blob/master/BleMouse.cpp#L55-L58)

Comment: I forgot to say, I'm trying to control my iPhone 7, and I'm not sure what the 127 and - 127 have to do with the physical and logical resolution of my iPhone 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values are used to determine the resolution multiplier for the mouse wheel, i.e. how much should be scrolled for one *click* of the mouse wheel.

For detailed documentation, see https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_2.pdf  on page 37.

In your case

> the Wheel control delivers one count per detent via a 1-byte field of an Input Report.

This means that you can send from -127 to 127 clicks at a time to the device you are connected to (in your case the iPhone). The OS then translates this to a scroll length in pixels or other metric it uses.